# error CS0117: 'ScoreSystem' does not contain a definition for 'HighscoreKey'

Tags: unity-game-engine, error-handling

i was just writing my script and this appeared while trying to test the game. heres my script

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using TMPro;

public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private TMP_Text HighscoreText;

    private void Start()
    {
        int Highscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(ScoreSystem.HighscoreKey, 0);
        
        HighscoreText.text = $"High Score: {Highscore}";
    }
    
    public void Play()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }
}
```

please help me, tq

Comment: Where is `ScoreSystem` coming from? I don't see it defined anywhere and I don't see anything online after a (brief) search. Whatever it's coming from, it doesn't have `HighscoreKey`. If you can link the documentation for `ScoreSystem` then you can see what it does and doesn't contain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is very clear: it says that inside the Score System class, it did not find the HighscoreKey variable.
To make this work, if you created the ScoreSystem class yourself, you should add a static string variable called HighscoreKey.

Like this:

```
public static string HighscoreKey = “…”;
```

Good Work!